# How to assign a function to a route functionally, without a route decorator in FastAPI?

Tags: python, fastapi

In Flask, it is possible to assign an arbitrary function to a route functionally like:

```py
from flask import Flask
app = Flask()

def say_hello():
    return "Hello"

app.add_url_rule('/hello', 'say_hello', say_hello)
```

which is equal to (with decorators):

```py
@app.route("/hello")
def say_hello():
    return "Hello"
```

Is there such a simple and functional way (`add_url_rule`) in FastAPI?

Comment: You can always call the decorator directly, of course `app.route("/hello")(say_hello)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [the `add_api_route` method](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/master/fastapi/routing.py#L504) to add a route to a router or an app programmtically:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, APIRouter


def foo_it():
    return {'Fooed': True}


app = FastAPI()
router = APIRouter()
router.add_api_route('/foo', endpoint=foo_it)
app.include_router(router)
app.add_api_route('/foo-app', endpoint=foo_it)
```

Both expose the same endpoint in two different locations:

```
λ curl http://localhost:8000/foo
{"Fooed":true}
λ curl http://localhost:8000/foo-app
{"Fooed":true}
```

Comment: To define the method `methods=["POST"]` should be passed as another keyword argument. Unfortunately there is no clear documentation about that.

Comment: You can safely assume that it supports all of the parameters that the regular view decorator does, since `app.get` / `app.post` just wraps the same `APIRouter` and the `api_route` method.

Answer (score 3):

Decorators are just syntactic sugar. They are simply functions that take another function as the first positional argument.

For example this:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/hello")
def say_hello():
    return "Hello"
```

Is equal to this:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
app = FastAPI()

def say_hello():
    return "Hello"


say_hello = app.get("/hello")(say_hello)
```

You don't need the assignment (setting the variable `say_hello`) as FastAPI always returns the function itself. That was to illustrate what decorators do.

I agree that the above is ugly and you might want to use the `app.add_api_route` as MatsLindh's answer suggests. However, I did not find that in the FastAPI documentation so not sure how official it is. Overall, it seems FastAPI's documentation lacks in this regard.